# Groovy vs Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Question 1**:What **modification** we should make(in Groovy) to ***run/install a package in Groovy which correctly run/installed in Fuerte***?
I have found out one that is in Groovy we have **'package.xml'** where as in Fuerte it is ** 'manifest.xml'**

**Question 2** What is the advantage of ***catkin over rosbuild***?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78886/groovy-vs-fuerte/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. It depends on whether the package has been ported from rosbuild to catkin.  Not all packages were converted.  If you need to convert there's a guide here: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild
2. A good place to get an overview of the design of catkin see: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1